# What's wrong with my program (scanf, C++)?

Tags: c++, scanf

What wrong with this program?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <cstdio> 
using namespace std; 
int N; 
char x[110]; 
int main() { 
    scanf("%d", &N); 
    while (N--) { 
        scanf("0.%[0-9]...", &x); 
        printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", x); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

this is a console application in VS 2013, here is a sample input and output:

input :

```
1 
0.123456789...
```

output

```
the digits are 0.123456789
```

but when I input this to this the output I get : The digits are 0 
I have tried inputitng and manually and by text, in Code::Blocks and VS 2013, but neither worked. And when inputting manually, the program doesn't wait for me to input the numbers after I have entered N. 
What should I do?

Comment: Always check return values of scanf funcs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
scanf("0.%[0-9]...", &x);
```

with

```
scanf(" 0.%[0-9]...", x);
```

You need to provide the starting location of the array which is `x`, not `&x`. Also, the space at the beginning will read all the whitespace characters and ignore it. So the `\n` left by `scanf("%d", &N);` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` in the loop fails, but you didn't notice.  It fails because it can't handle a newline before the literal `0`.  So, fix the format string by adding a space, and the code by testing the return value from `scanf()`:

```
if (scanf(" 0.%[0-9]...", x) != 1)
    …oops — wrong format…
```

The blank in the format string skips zero or more white space characters; newlines (and tabs and spaces, etc) are white space characters.

You also don't want the `&` in front of `x`.  Strictly, it causes a type violation: `%[0-9]` expects a `char *` but you pass a `char (*)[100]` which is quite a different type.  However, it happens to be the same address, so you get away with it, but correct code shouldn't do that.